# How can I read socket binding with JBOSS CLI?

Tags: jboss, jboss-cli

I'm using `RED HAT JBOSS ENTERPRISE APPLICATION PLATFORM 6.4.2.GA`. Using EAP Management (`Configuration` -> `Connector` -> `Mail` -> `JNDI Name` -> `View`)

I'm able to see value inside of `.xml` file:

```
# grep remote-destination /etc/jbossas/standalone/standalone-full-ha.xml
            <remote-destination host="X" port="25"/>
            <remote-destination host="X" port="5445"/>
            <remote-destination host="X" port="5445"/>
            <remote-destination host="X" port="25"/>
            <remote-destination host="X" port="25"/>
#
```

How can I get value of `Socket Binding` via `jboss-cli.sh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use only `standard-sockets` socket binding group, then use  following JBoss CLI command to list remote-destinations:

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets \
    /remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=*:read-resource()
```

If you use more socket groups then call the similar command for every group.

Or you can read whole socket-binding configuration at once:

```
/socket-binding-group=*:read-resource(recursive=true)
```